# Opening .txt file via executable file (compiled c++ code) on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, compilation

I have an issue with my compiled c++ code on Mac. I have written an app that read .txt file, but when I compile the source code via

```
g++ main.cpp -o MyApp
```

and run it, MyApp is not opening the .txt file. (I have both executable and .txt file in the same directory).

But when I just compile my .cpp file, not making executable, just compiling (getting .out from .cpp) and run it via terminal, it works perfectly.

```
g++ main.cpp
./a.out
```

I am opening the file by:

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("list.txt");
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue and connect the executable file with that text file? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Any chance to get the error code after the opening ?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp` and `g++ main.cpp -o MyApp` are doing the exact same thing, the only difference is the name of the resulting file. Both commands make an executable (a.out is an executable). It is highly unlikely that the story you are telling is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally found the solution. I tried open .txt file with absolute path to and everything works fine. The only problem now is when I move the project to another directory so I have to compile it again with different path.

Helped:

```
myfile.open("/Users/macbook/Desktop/Program/list.txt");
```

instead of

```
myfile.open("list.txt");
```